# Oracle APEX 4.2 How to store string and access from any page?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm a complete noob and have only been learning this since last night.

I have an APEX application with a few forms and reports that I have managed to get working correctly if I provide the exact SQL statement in the source box. What I want to do is be able to set a variable that I can access from any page.

I want to be able to return its value to use in my SQL source clause in my forms when the pages load and I also want to be able to assign its value maybe via a process, branch or button (i'm still learning what they are propperly) on any page.

I've been at this for hours now and the tiny amount of help I can find on this is completely beyond me and its driving me mad, so if anyone can help me figure out how to do this it would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one application item (Shared Components -> Application Items) and then set it from your PL/SQL code using APEX_UTIL package (apex_util.set_session_state('TESTE', 'Hello').